# rsync copy only files facade

Tags: rsync, file-copy

Is there a way to mirror a directory structure and files there contained with rsync,  giving out facade zero length files?

I mean, mirroring dirs (`-d` flag I think) exactly as they are, while not copying the files and substituting them some sort or symlink(?) or something like an empty file with his name and attr and no size?
In short I want to mirror an env entirely while minimizing uninportqnt files size.

Comment: cp -r --attributes-only SOURCE_DIR TARGET_DIR

Comment: @Costas You should post this as an answer.